# Get rid of the blurry outline with SetWindowCompositionAttribute

Tags: c#, cmd, border, blur, undocumented-behavior

I am writing an app that will use the undocumented SetWindowCompositionAttribute function to blur the command prompt background. However when using it, there is a weird outline that I can't seem to get rid of with my multiple attempts:

[image]

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it causes by the shadow attribute.The scope of the window includes the shadow which need the extra scope over the actual size of the command window.So the scope of the blur is not the actual size of the command window.You can try to remove the shadow attribute of the command window.